# Why $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x-a}{x^2-a^2}=\frac{1}{2a}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Given that $a\neq0$, what is the value of the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x-a}{x^2-a^2}$$

I know the answer is $\frac{1}{2a}$ but why? If I substitute $a$ into the equation I get an ind of the form $\frac00$, I would factories but I can factorize the rational function given, so how do I get to such result?

Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't all too sure how to correct the last sentence... Please let me know if I got the rest right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** ${}(x^2-a^2)=(x+a)(x-a).$

Comment: goosh! al rite! thanks very much :)